# How to keep a key-based cache working through code changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I'm implementing a [key-based cache](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3113-how-key-based-cache-expiration-works) in my Rails application (which is mostly just an API for a single-page Javascript application, so we're not caching any view code, just the results of methods that are expensive to compute).

I'm concerned about the situation where I make a code change which ends up affecting a cached method such that it gives different results. Since the code change will not invalidate anything, I will be serving stale data.

What are good practices for dealing with this issue? If I do nothing, developers will have to be aware of when their code changes might affect cached methods, and invalidate the caches manually before deploy.

I know that Rails solves this problem for views by appending the md5 of the view template to the cache key. But it's harder because these are not just views. The analogous thing, I think, would be to version each of my cache keys with the current commit's hash, but this would lead to total invalidation of all cache keys whenever we make a new commit, which is unacceptable.

The problem doesn't seem specific to key-based as opposed to other types of cache, but I thought it was helpful context.